# Matrix inside a matrix column

Tags: matrices

I'm typing a numeric way to solve the Jacobian Inverse for Denavit-Hartenberg method. I need to write the vectors z_i and t_i inside the matrix but I couldn't find a way to do it with standard LaTeX packages (I'm doing a Google Docs presentation and the extensions only recognize standard packages). Here is a picture (made in MSPaint) of what I'am talking about:

[image]

Edit: for now, I only have this piece of the code:

```
^0A_i = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\cdots & \cdots & z_i & t_i\\
\cdots & \cdots & z_i & t_i\\
\cdots & \cdots & z_i & t_i\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's perfectly possible to nest matrices

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
{}^0A_i = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\cdots & \cdots & & \\
\cdots & \cdots & \smash{\begin{bmatrix}{}\\z_i\\{}\end{bmatrix}} & \smash{\begin{bmatrix}{}\\t_i\\{}\end{bmatrix}} \\
\cdots & \cdots &  & \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For an even number of rows you can use \raisebox or \multirow.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

This is very easy with `nicematrix` package

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix} % for easy customization of matrices

\begin{document}

$^0A_i = 
\begin{bNiceMatrix}[margin]
    \cdots & \cdots & \Block{3-1}{Z_{i}}  & \Block{3-1}{t_{i}}
\\
    \cdots & \cdots &  &
\\
    \cdots & \cdots &  &
\\
    \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots
\CodeAfter
\SubMatrix{[}{1-3}{3-3}{]}
\SubMatrix{[}{1-4}{3-4}{]}
\end{bNiceMatrix}$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can nest matrices in matrices:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
{}^0A_1=
\begin{bmatrix}
\begin{matrix}
\cdots & \cdots \\
\cdots & \cdots \\
\cdots & \cdots
\end{matrix} &
\begin{bmatrix}
\\ z_1 \\ {}
\end{bmatrix} &
\begin{bmatrix}
\\ t_1 \\ {}
\end{bmatrix} \\
\begin{matrix}\cdots & \cdots\end{matrix} & \cdots & \cdots
\end{bmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]